# loss and val_loss significantly different from each other

Tags: validation, keras

I did the regular train test split on the data and tried to fit the model. What is suprising is that my loss value is significantly diffent from my val_loss. Why is that? I understand they can't be the same, but their scale should be at least on the same level right? At first I thought that the test size was too small, so I checked the 50/50 split. Values for loss are still noticeably higher than val_loss.
Is the metric different? How do I set the same metric.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128,input_shape = (X.shape[1], X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam')
model.summary()
model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=128,
          epochs=200,
          validation_data=(X_test,y_test),
          callbacks=[early_stop]
         )

Epoch 1/200
1507/1507 [==============================] - 7s 5ms/step - loss: 27.5249 - val_loss: 1.2039
Epoch 2/200
1507/1507 [==============================] - 7s 5ms/step - loss: 25.0813 - val_loss: 1.1662
Epoch 3/200
1507/1507 [==============================] - 7s 5ms/step - loss: 24.5255 - val_loss: 1.1632
Epoch 4/200
1507/1507 [==============================] - 7s 5ms/step - loss: 25.0556 - val_loss: 1.1731
```

Comment: did you shuffle your data before doing the train/validation split?

Comment: Yes. I did train_test_split with some random state.

Comment: if i were you i would try do the split and shuffle "manually" to make sure it is true random, then i would try with a non-recurrent network,